# Fiat Punto Grande 2007 does not start right away

Tags: starting, fiat

I own a 2nd hand 2007 automatic Fiat Punto Grande. For some time now, I have been experiencing strange behavior when I try to start the engine: Sometimes, it starts right away, i.e., normally, but sometimes I need to hold the key on the "ignite" position for a certain amount of time before the engine starts. This time can be anywhere between 5 to 30 seconds, and at times, even more. There are some really annoying times when I need to turn the key a few times before the car starts. I tried to find some kind of pattern as to when this problem occurs and when it does not, but so far, without any success. It seems to be totally random. After the car starts, the car runs normally. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the engine turn over during the "no start" events or you turn the key and nothing happens?

Comment: @mikes no the engine does not turn over. Nothing happens.

Comment: I had an issue where my battery was not very well connected once and exhibited this same type of behavior. You may try cleaning and retightening the battery clamps and see if that helps.

Comment: @Paulster2 thanks for the tip. I'll try that ASAP and see what I come up with.

Comment: I tried cleaning and retightening the battery clamps but experienced the same issue :( . I'm no expert, but if the battery was the issue, wouldn't I experience trouble after the car finally starts as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the robotic-gear after all. Apparently, the gear robot wasn't alway putting the car into gear when starting, which caused the car not to start. Nothing left to do but send it to the garage.